# How to reduce multiattack penalty for bombs?

Tags: attack, pathfinder-2e, throwing-things

Is there some way to reduce or avoid the multi-attack penalty when throwing weapons?

So far the only thing I found is the [Dual Thrower](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1951) feat which is completely useless because it requires you to already hold both weapons and I couldn't find any way to draw two weapons with a single action.

If it helps I'm looking into Alchemist using bombs. Quick Bomber would let me throw up to 3 bombs in a round but that's hardly useful with standard attack penalties.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why holding two weapons/bombs at a time is infeasible? I see that Quick Bomber allows you to draw and Strike with a bomb in one Action, but that doesn't necessarily mean that's the only way to make 2-3 attacks with Bombs. Also, is making three attacks necessary to the question, or would 2 Bombs per round, but with lower MAP be valid?

Comment: What resources do you have available to put toward this? I.E. Could you take an archetype? Change classes and use an Alchemist/bomber archetype? Only non-archetype Feats? Just money for items? And is there a level you'd specifically want this on-line by, or just the lowest level possible?

Comment: @Ifusaso 2 bombs per round would be fine if it came with lower or negated penalty on the second one. Throwing a third bomb with high penalty is mostly a waste of ammo anyway.

Comment: @Ifusaso Any resources are fine, I want to know my options and then adjust accordingly. Low level would be preferable.

Comment: @Ifusaso as for why holding two bombs is infeasible well obviously that's only feasible in the first round but after throwing them my hands are empty so using Dual Thrower becomes a 4-actions thing which is too costly.

Comment: @enumag mind if I edit the question for this to be "bombs" instead of "thrown weapons"? That's a pretty important constraint - bombs aren't weapons and their consumable nature makes a lot of solutions harder (if even there is one, I'm still looking).

Comment: @ESCE "Bombs are martial thrown weapons with a range increment of 20 feet." https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=703
but I edited the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Dual Thrower

This feat you've mentioned is only limited by needing to have two bombs in your hands, which can be worked around:

- [Valet Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=38): You can spend one action to have them place two bombs in your hands, and there's many ways to get a familiar like the 1st-level alchemist feat [Alchemical Familiar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=92)
- Double Brew: As a 9th-level [alchemist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=1) you can use Quick Alchemy to spontaneously create two bombs as a single action, ready to be thrown.
- Start combat with two bombs ready: Only works for the first turn, but in practice your resources might be limited where early on this is sufficient.

Pursuing this feat to make two strikes without MAP also opens up future options like the 14th-level feat [Dual Onslaught](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1955). For most Dual-Weapon Warriors getting a free successful attack once a round is good, but many bombs have very powerful effects on a success beyond damage.

### [Flurry Ranger](https://2e.aonprd.com/HuntersEdge.aspx?ID=1)

Against your hunted target you get only a -3 MAP for the second bomb, or -2 at 17th-level. You could pick up alchemist as an archetype for getting daily bombs and Quick Bomber.

Comment: Looking into familiar abilities there are quite a few beneficial for Alchemist so I might want to get more than the standard two abilities. But somehow Enhanced Familiar doesn't have the Alchemist trait. But then there is Familiar Master Dedication which seems like it can grant Enhanced Familiar to Alchemist anyway? What's up with that?

Comment: @enumag Basically instead of putting familiar enhancing feats in every class, there's the Familiar Master archetype that any character can take to get or enhance their familiar using their class feats.

Comment: I took it on my high level Wizard with Free Archetype rules in play. It provided some very neat options, although I don't know that I'd spend Class Feats on it normally.

Comment: There's also some equipment that can help draw more bombs as free actions: the gloves of storing, the retrieval prism, and the thousand-blade thesis.

Comment: @Ruse I think that'd make a good alternative answer - some people might want to do this without feat investment or class changes.